# Porting lighttpd server to Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, arm, lighttpd

i am trying to port lighttpd to android so that uses can execute php script from there android device
by hitting localhost:port from broswser but my script is not working properly

Here is runtime java code

public class RunTimeProvider {
    boolean isLoaded = false;

```
ProcessBuilder mysqlBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {
        "/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/mysqld",
        "--defaults-file=/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/my.ini",
        "--user=root",
        "--language=/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/share/mysql/english" });

ProcessBuilder phpBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {
        "/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/php-cgi-ext", "-c",
        "data/data/com.Punk.Qs/php.ini" });
ProcessBuilder lighttpdBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {
        "/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/lighttpd", "-f",
        "data/data/com.Punk.Qs/lighttpd.conf" });

public void execute() {
    File fphp = new File("/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/php-cgi-ext");
    File flighttp = new File("/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/lighttpd");
    File fmysql = new File("/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/mysqld");
    if (fphp.exists() && flighttp.exists() && fmysql.exists()) {

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "chmod 777 /data/data/com.Punk.Qs/lighttpd");
            lighttpdBuilder.start();

            //NativeApp(
                    "/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/lighttpd -f data/data/com.Punk.Qs/lighttpd.conf",
                    "lighttpd");

            Log.w("Lighttpd Started ", "Lighttpd successfully started");
        } catch (IOException e) {

            Log.w("Lighttpd Startup failed ", e);
            new ErrorLogger("Lighttpd", e.toString());
        }
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "chmod 777 /data/data/com.Punk.Qs/mysqld");
            mysqlBuilder.start();
            //NativeApp(
                    "/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/mysqld --defaults-file=/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/my.ini --user=root --language=/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/share/mysql/english",
                    "mySQl");
            Log.d("mySQL Started ", "mySQL successfully started");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("mySQL Startup failed ", e);
            new ErrorLogger("mySQl", e.toString());
        }
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "chmod 777 /data/data/com.Punk.Qs/php-cgi-ext");
            phpBuilder.start();
            //NativeApp(
                    "/data/data/com.Punk.Qs/php-cgi-ext -c data/data/com.Punk.Qs/php.ini",
                    "phpCgi");

            Log.d("PHP Started ", "PHP successfully started");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("PHP Startup failed ", e);
            new ErrorLogger("phpCgi", e.toString());

        }
    } else {
        Log.w("Error Runime Lib", "RunTime Libs is missing");

    }
    // return b;

}

public void NativeApp(String cmd, String tag) {

    Process nativeApp = null;

    Log.d("Executing :", cmd);
    try {

        nativeApp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("RunTime Error : ", e.toString());
        new ErrorLogger("RunTime", e.toString());
    }

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            nativeApp.getInputStream()));
    int read;
    char[] buffer = new char[4096 * 8];
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    try {

        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IO Error : ", e.toString());
        new ErrorLogger("IO", e.toString());
    }

    // Waits for the command to finish.
    try {
        nativeApp.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        Log.e("InterruptedException : ", e.toString());
        new ErrorLogger("IntExp", e.toString());
    }

    String nativeOutput = output.toString();
    if (nativeOutput != null)
        isLoaded = true;
    Log.d("Output from : " + cmd, nativeOutput);
    new ErrorLogger("RunLib", nativeOutput);
}
```

}

method RunTimePRovider().execute() will be invoked when user clicks on Button

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to go for a opensource project [this](https://github.com/DroidPHP/DroidPHP) and go through the code copy `assets`
 and then check it on your device or emulator i have also used this project to use `php` and `lighthttpd` in `android..`

Comment: +1 for first to answer, and thanks a lot for using my app i have developed this application i.e `DroidPHP`. and this question was ask before. the initial release of droidphp.

Comment: Sir r u developer of 'Droidphp'

Comment: what a pleasure to talk to you please be with me for 10 mins. please??

Comment: i want to ask that i am using droidphp and i am running a script that writes data to a text file,the script runs fine but the data is not written to my text file do i have set any permission or anything please help.And the work u have done is a like a jewel for me :) i love DroidPhp.Please reply.....

Comment: @punk i have submitted a issue for droidphp on github please read it... Thank u..